# Select by one character using shift + arrow does not work in Terminal

Tags: terminal, keyboard

After fresh reinstall of macOS (started with High Sierra, not updated up to Big Sur), I am unable to use Shift + ← and Shift + → in Terminal, it returns symbols instead of selecting one character on left or right side.

- Shift + ← returns **e[1;2C**
- Shift + → returns **e[1;2D**

I was unable to find fix, I have tried using Terminal and iTerm2.

How to fix this?

//EDIT: Mapping shift-right to `\e[1;2C`, and shift-left to `\e[1;2D` from [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/115928/terminal-problem-with-ctrl-arrow-and-shift-arrow-keys) does not work.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR -
you need to add custom settings by going to **iTerm** `Preferences > Profiles > Keys` and add your new custom key-bindings.

---

In case you're interested to know every step, you should checkout the [answer from stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30055402/how-to-select-text-in-iterm-with-shiftarrow), which in turn refers another [answer from superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/1051668/select-full-word-in-iterm2-using-alt-shift-arrow/1216606#1216606) sister-site!

Refer answers by @Merlin and @danylokos in ref answer from stackoverflow

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however this does not solve the issue. Proposed solution uses some weird selection mode used by iTerm which I do not like - I just need to highlight the text using good old way using shift and arror. Also even if this will solve my issue, I cannot reproduce it in Terminal...

Comment: "Good Old Way" was never selecting using shift and arrow keys!
But anyways, this is called customising key-bindings.
Alternatively, you can do it using external applications like `screen` or `tmux`

Comment: I am not gonna argue about default behaviour of SHIFT and LEFT & RIGHT arrow keys, because it is used to extend the selection since MS-DOS...maybe earlier. But I am going to check `screen` or `tmux`, but it's strange to me that I need external app to fix native bahaviour... :/

Answer (score 0):

iTerm2 > Preferences > Profiles > Keys > Key Mappings > Presets > Terminal.app Compability

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful to readers as to how/why your "answer" provides a solution asked in the original question.

Comment: do you mean it should be changed to `Natural Text Editing` for it to work in the expected(from question) way?